# How to read OPC Values

Tags: c#, plc, opc

I am having `opctechs OPC` server which reads & writes values from PLC. Now I want to read the values through C#. I have no idea to write a code to read values & searched through out the internet, but got no solution.

How can I perform the action ?

Thanks

Comment: contact opctechs OPC for C# documentations.

Comment: Simply googling for "opc c# client" gives enough material to start with.

Comment: is not a clear questions!
 
Which protocol ?

Which PLC  brand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install **QuickOPC 5.23(.NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0)** or **QuickOPC 5.31(.NET Framework 4.5)** from **http://opclabs.com/products/quickopc/downloads**

Create a **C#** project in **VisualStudio**.

Add the reference, `OpcLabs.EasyOpcClassic.dll` to the project.

```
using OpcLabs.EasyOpc;
using OpcLabs.EasyOpc.DataAccess;

public class Demand
{
    private void frm_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadPLCvalue();
    }

    private void ReadPLCvalue()
    {
        EasyDAClient objClient = new EasyDAClient();
        object sValue = null;

        try {
            sValue = objClient.ReadItemValue(PLCServerMachineName, PLCServerID, PLCTagName);

        } catch (OpcException ex) {
        }

        StoreToDB(sValue);
    }

    private void StoreToDB(object source)
    {
        //Database operations to store the value.
    }
    public Demand()
    {
        Load += frm_Load;
    }
}
```